# How to accelerate the list page when objects have attributes with thousands of possibilities

Tags: category, performance, product-attribute

I'm working on a magento website that have hundreds of products with, each of them, having more than 5 thousands of options in a dropdownlist (in a custom attribute, using [this plugin](http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html)

I know that this is stupid to store that much data in the dropdownlist but I can't do a thing to change that (client, boss, wimey wibbly wobbly stuff, etc) [1]

Since I imported all my products with their respective DropDownList, the website is very slow to show the page `mywebsite/any-category`.

It seems that the view that is rendering the products for a cateogry get some products (first 9th for example) and all the attributes (even if each of them have a dropdown with 5K of options)

Does someone have ever encountered this kind of problem before ?
Is there a way of getting a product collection with only certain attributes ? (or to exclude some ?)

**Edited :** 
Even if I have a dropdownlist of 5K elements, these element are for the "width and height" of the products with the following format `6x7`.

When the products are showed at the screen, I hide this dropdownlist and show two other dropdown of MAXIMUM 72 values. The users won't even notice  they dropdown of 5K elements.

**I really just need to optimize the speed of the category page because the product page is  already fast.**

Comment: There must by another way to get products in magento without loading all the custom options ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few numbers.

Assume all your options have a value with 4 digits and every label is only five bytes long, so we have something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1234">label</option>
```

This is 35 characters. `35 characters * 5000 options * 9 products = 1,575,000 bytes`

Calculating with 1000er steps because it is easier, this are **1.5MB(!!)** of HTML. What do you think how long it takes for a browser to build a DOM with 1.5MB of text-data? :-) Here is your problem - I think.

I have no idea what you are selling, but I can't imagine a way where a customer selects something from a 5k long dropdown - NEVER.

Comment: This isn't helping me at all. I edited the question to add more detail but the user won't see this dropdownlist because I generate two other dropdown with JS and hide the other. I know that this is probably the wrong way of doing things but I don't have a choice, the only thing that I need is to raise the speed of the category page because, these dropdownlist aren't even showed on this page

Comment: If they are hidden, they are still parsed and created in the DOM. If you select an entry from the select, why you don't just use a hidden text field and write the value into this?

Comment: Because there's only some possible value that the user can select but what you are trying to resolve has nothing to do with the initial question. Do you know any way of getting products for a category but only certain attributes (I don't want to get my dropdownlist attribute in my category page)

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Yes: All the attributes are loaded which are marked as "show on product list" which means `used_in_product_listing = 1` in `catalog_eav_attribute`, so just switching the attribute off (in backend or in setup script) changes this behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the heads up ! But since I needed my attribute to have a custom price, a weight and a quantity, I used the plugin cited above. Do you know it ? If yes, do you know where I could set the these two variables for my attribute ?

Comment: no, and you are talking about custom options, not attributes! big difference and I have no idea how to handle this.